# A euchre deck contains twenty-four cards, with six ranks (9, 10, J, Q, K, A) and four suits. A hand in euchre contains five cards...

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> A euchre deck contains twenty-four cards, with six ranks (9, 10, J, Q, K, A) and four suits.  A hand in euchre contains five cards.  How many different euchre hands are there?

**What I did:**

$\frac{24!}{(19!)(5!)} = 42,504$ combinations

(however, this appears to be wrong on my quiz)

**So my question is, what am I doing wrong here?**

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have the answer that is the expected answer?  Your answer of $\frac{24!}{19!5!}$ is correct if we assume that the order of the cards within the hand doesn't matter (*and we are looking at only a specific player's hand and ignoring the faceup card by the dealer*).  If we are looking at how many ways the deck can be dealt, that is a different problem.

Comment: You do have a small typo, $\binom{24}{5}=4250\color{blue}{4}$ not $42505$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you, that was the problem! :)